# Jackson Custom Deserializer Not Working In Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

I created a custom deserializer for my entities but it keeps on throwing exception:

I have two classes: AppUser and AppUserAvatar

**AppUser.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class AppUser implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3536455219051825651L;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 256)
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "is_active", nullable = false)
    private boolean active;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser", targetEntity = AppUserAvatar.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<AppUserAvatar> appUserAvatars;

    //// Getters and Setters and toString() ////
}
```

**AppUserAvatar.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_avatar")
public class AppUserAvatar extends BaseEntityD implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8992425872747011681L;

    @Column(name = "avatar", nullable = false)
    @Digits(integer = 20, fraction = 0)
    @NotEmpty
    private Long avatar;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = AppUserDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private AppUser appUser;

    //// Getters and Setters and toString() ////
}
```

**AppUserDeserializer.java**
package com.nk.accountservice.deserializer;

```
import com.edoctar.accountservice.config.exception.InputNotFoundException;
import com.edoctar.accountservice.domain.candidate.AppUser;
import com.edoctar.accountservice.service.candidate.AppUserService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class AppUserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9012464195937554378L;

    private AppUserService appUserService;

    @Autowired
    public void setAppUserService(AppUserService appUserService) {
        this.appUserService = appUserService;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        Long userId = node.asLong();
        System.out.println(node);
        System.out.println(node.asLong());
        AppUser appUser = appUserService.findById(userId);
        System.out.println("appuser: " + appUser);
        if (appUser == null) try {
            throw new InputNotFoundException("User not found!");
        } catch (InputNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return appUser;
    }
}
```

Sample xhr boy is:

```
{
  "appUser": 1,
  "avatar": 1
}
```

An exception is thrown each time I submit the request.

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.edoctar.accountservice.domain.candidate.AppUserAvatar["appUser"])]
```

[image: Here's the screenshoot of my console.]

I discovered that the `appUserService.findById()` method is not being called. I am really confused. I don't know where I went wrong. Will be greatful for any solution. Thanks.

Comment: Breakpoint in the deserializer and find what is `null`. I suspect `appUserService` is not injected and you get NPE there

Comment: @NiVeR Here is the observation: `node: "1"` and `appUserService = null`. I don't know why it's null. I annotated the service with `@Service` and I guess I have properly injected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated answer:**
You can't use autowired properties because you are not in the Spring context. You are passing the class `AppUserDeserializer` as a reference in the annotation

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = AppUserDeserializer.class)
```

In this situation is the *FasterJackson* library that creates the instance of `AppUserDeserializer`, so the `Autowired` annotation is not taken in consideration.

You can solve your problem with a little trick. Add a static reference to the instance created by spring in the `AppUserService`:

```
 @Service
 public AppUserService {

   public static AppUserService instance;

   public AppUserService() {
     // Modify the constructor setting a static variable holding a
     // reference to the instance created by spring
     AppUserService.instance = this;
   }

   ...
 }
```

Use that reference in the `AppUserDeserializer`:

```
public class AppUserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer implements Serializable {

    private AppUserService appUserService;

    public AppUserDeserializer() {
      // Set appUserService to the instance created by spring
      this.appUserService = AppUserService.instance;
    }

    ...

}
```

---

Original answer: To have a correct initialization of an `Autowired` property you have to annotate your class `AppUserDeserializer`, otherwise `appUserService` is null if you don't explicitly init it using the set method.

Try to annotate `AppUserDeserializer` with `@Component`:

```
@Component   // Add this annotation
public class AppUserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer implements Serializable {
   ...
}
```

Comment: After annotating the `AppUserDeserializer` with `@Component`, `appUserService` is still null;

Comment: Do you have @Service on appUserService?

Comment: Yes I do. `org.springframework.stereotype.Service` annotated on the service. I have injecting this appUserService bean in various classes, with no problem.

Comment: @byteHunt3r are you creating the AppUserDeserializer with an explicit call to new AppUserDeserializer() ? If you do that you are not using the instance created by spring that has been initialized with AppUserService

Comment: I used it directly with the `@JsonDeserializer` on the target fields. e.g `@JsonDeserialize(using = AppUserDeserializer.class)`.

Comment: @byteHunt3r I updated the answer taking in to account the informations that you gave me and looking better at your code.

Comment: Wow. Thanks very much. It works. I have learnt something new from you.

Answer (score 1):

You could go on and try to inject correctly the `AppUserService` but according to me this is not the cleanest solution. Generally I dislike the idea to use `@Entity` as communication models or view models. In this way you are coupling the entity to the producer/consumer of the view model. You are basically short-circuiting the model part.

What I would do is to map the contents of the json to a different class in deserialization phase, and use this one later on to construct the corresponding entity.

Comment: I have only one AppUserService. I even injected the repository direct, but same null result. I guess I'll get rid of this approach and work with view models.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this line of code:

```
private boolean active;
```

to

```
private Boolean active;
```

boolean primitive can't handle nulls and may result in NPE.

Comment: Not sure this matters in this case